# Smooth scrolling function including page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to write a smooth scrolling function that can handle if the href needs to load a new page first then run the scroll.

I have seen a few options where adding `/page-template.html#anchor` to the href, but with a dynamic site where the homepage url would just be `/#anchor`.

So the below code isn't seeing the slash as a part of the target href.

```
const $anchor = $('a')

$anchor.on('click', function(event) {

    if (this.hash !== "") {
      event.preventDefault()
      let hash = this.hash

      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
      }, 800, function(){
        window.location.hash = hash
      })
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of worked out a way to achieve this, but it's not tremendously pretty. Any advice on improving it would be appreciated.

```
// If loading a page with a hash in the URL, scroll to it
if (window.location.hash) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('html, body').scrollTop(0)
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
            }, 1000)
    }, 0)
}

// Get the current url path
const currUrl = window.location.pathname

$anchor.on('click', function(e) {

    // Get the href and a hash into variables
    const href = $(this).attr('href')
    const hash = this.hash

    // If a hash is present
    if (hash) {

        // Check if there is a URl path before the hash
        if (href.charAt(0) !== '#') {

            // Check if this URL path matches the current page's href
            if (currUrl == href.split('#')[0]) {
                e.preventDefault()

                // As they match, just run the scroll within the same page
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
                }, 800, function() {
                    window.location.hash = hash
                })
            }

        // There is no URL accompanying the hash, so it's got to be within the same page
        } else {
            e.preventDefault()
            // Run smooth scrolling within the page
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
            }, 800, function() {
                window.location.hash = hash
            })
        }
    }
})
```